# Transaction-dependent signing

Tags: safe-core

I’m trying to figure out whether it is possible to set up a Safe as follows:

1. Funds can be withdrawn from a safe only using n of m multisig;
2. However, a safe could interact with the whitelisted DeFi (like Uniswap) position manager contract using just one key with transactions being signed and sent via the web3.py library.
   The idea is that the key that signs the transactions with the Uniswap can be eventually compromised, so it should be able to interact with the DeFi contract only, while the funds in the safe should be protected by multiple signatures.
   Maybe the Allowances module can be used for it? (https://github.com/safe-global/safe-modules/blob/main/modules/allowances/README.md)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible; you can configure your safe normally with an x-out-of-y scheme, and then add a custom module to it. Modules interact directly with safes, regardless of the setup. So since the module will override this check, you can simply define that it will be able to interact with Uniswap (and only with Uniswap); it won't not need to trigger the x-out-of-y scheme when interacting with it.

You can learn more about building custom modules [here](https://docs.safe.global/advanced/smart-account-modules).

Hope it helps; best, Louis.

Comment: Thank you! Is the Allowances module suitable for that or a custom module is needed?

Comment: No a custom module will be needed to have the exact features that you need.